# Проблема с нахождением полуслова "авва" в тексте

Tags: c++

Представлено вот такое задание:
[image: Задание]

Вот мой код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    string aBBa = "Аввакий Аввакум Аввакиевич";
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    cout << "Выражение: " << aBBa << endl;
    do {
        if (aBBa[i] == 'а')
            j++;
        i++;
    } while (aBBa[i] != '\0');
    cout << "Кол-во букв а = " << j << endl;
    i = 0;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Мне удалось только понять, как находить количество букв в тексте, если же я попробую найти полуслово тем же способом (а именно во фрагменте ниже напишу вместо a - авва),

```
if (aBBa[i] == 'а')
                j++;
```

то программа откажется что-либо вычислять (значение будет равно нулю). 
[image: Попытка выполнения]

Так работает не только с русскими словосочетаниями, пробовал вместо авва вводить abba и менять текст в переменной на английский -  та же проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Вы указали что используете C++ в метке, но Ваше решение не задействует возможности С++.

На данный момент Вы пытались использовать идею поиска по символьный (почитайте - метод Бойера-Мура-Хорспула или просто std::boyer_moore_searcher, они есть в std) Вы можете реализовать его Сами или посмотреть готовую реализацию.

Но давайте отойдем от Си-стайла и явного посимвольного сравнения.  Ваш подход больше подходит под С. Вы можете добавить еще один вопрос и попросить реализовать это на СИ.

Посмотрите на Вариант решения на C++ который Вам подойдет.
std::string уже умеет находить подстроку (и даже все подстроки) без явного манипулирования программистом данными.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main([[maybe_unused]] int argc, [[maybe_unused]] char *argv[]) {
    std::string str{"Аввакий Аввакум Аввакиевич"};
    std::string key{"Авва"};
    std::size_t n {0};

    for (size_t pos = str.find(key, 0); pos != std::string::npos; ++n) {
        pos = str.find(key,pos+1);
    }

    std::cout << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [[maybe_unused]] для аргументов  main, совершенно лишняя анотация

Comment: Впрочем, в Си тоже есть аналогичная функция -- [strstr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan -  1. Это не аннотация, а атрибут. 2. Вы не правы ( Вы же не знаете с какими я влагами собираю код).

Comment: Флагами* - опечатка вышла

Comment: @avp -  да, там все идентично (strstr)